# Assign PHP variables in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on integrating external code. Following is the code:

```
if(count($_POST))
pay_page(array('key'=>'gtKFFx','txnid'=>'shanil','amount'=>'100');
```

There are static values. I want to assign php variables to this array:

```
if(count($_POST))
pay_page(array('key'=>'gtKFFx','txnid'=><?php echo $b; ?>,'amount'=>'10');
```

How do I achieve that? Can somebody help?

Comment: Just `'txnid' => $b`, no need to echo.

Comment: That was the mistake, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(count($_POST))
    pay_page(array('key'=>'gtKFFx','txnid'=> $b,'amount'=>'10'));
```

This should work.

Comment: @panther Thanks for pointing out, I have corrected the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just write there `$b`, no `<?php` etc. You are in PHP script, so there is no reason why to begin PHP script again.

```
if(count($_POST))
    pay_page(array('key' => 'gtKFFx', 'txnid' => $b, 'amount' => 10));
```

Note: 
- There was missing bracket at the end of the script
- amount is number, so it should be written without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in out of php script i.e your code is correct.

Now you are in php script only. so **echo**  is not required.

so just use like below code:

```
if(count($_POST))
    pay_page(array('key' => 'gtKFFx', 'txnid' => $b, 'amount' => 10));
```

I think this is useful.